# create section without printing it

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

I am working on my own recipe collection. I want to add sections to the TOC and maybe have them in the running head but I do not want them to be printed to the body of the page at all. Each page shall only display a recipe. The typical commands `\section` or `\addsec` do not have such functionality. The always print the section title to the body.

Is there such a command or is it necessary to create that on my own?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Recipe 1}
This is recipe 1
\newpage

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Recipe 2}
This is recipe 2
\newpage

\end{document}
```

---

### EDIT

In order to achieve what you've requested in the comment, you can modify the above code as follows (hope I haven't misunderstood)

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\phantomsection
\stepcounter{section}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thesection}Recipe 1}
This is recipe 1
\newpage

\phantomsection
\stepcounter{section}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thesection}Recipe 2}
This is recipe 2
\newpage

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Something like

```
\newcommand{\invisiblesection}[1]{%
  \phantomsection%
  \stepcounter{section}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thesection}#1}%
  }
```

to be used as

```
\invisiblesection{Recipe 1}
```

could be useful...

Comment: No, I want them to be numbered as if they were normal section. I have chapters that are printed. And I want to add tocs for each chapter, so I need the normal numbering.

Comment: It works, however the formatting is different to the format that koma-script uses. The default section has a visible separation between number and text which the new section command does not have. That is why I would rather reuse existing commands to preserve the formatting.